# Apply CIHardLightBlendMode with 50% alpha

Tags: ios, swift, alpha, core-image, cifilter

I'm blending a CIImage with a speckled grey (film grain like) file:

```
    var hardLightBlendFilter = CIFilter(name: "CIHardLightBlendMode")!
    var inputImage: CIImage = ...
    let grainImage = CIImage(cgImage: (UIImage(named: "Grain")?.cgImage)!)

    hardLightBlendFilter.setValue(inputImage, forKey: kCIInputBackgroundImageKey)
    hardLightBlendFilter.setValue(grainImage, forKey: kCIInputImageKey)
```

How can I apply this effect by only 50%?

I tried to find a way to set the alpha of `grainImage` to see what the effect of that would be.  But couldn't figure that out yet.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not very intuitive, but you can use the `CIColorMatrix` filter to manipulate the image's alpha value:

```
let colorMatrixFilter = CIFilter(name: "CIColorMatrix")!
colorMatrixFilter.setValue(grainImage, forKey: kCIInputImageKey)
colorMatrixFilter.setValue(CIVector(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, z: 0.0, w: 0.5), forKey: "inputAVector") // where 0.5 is the factor applied to alpha
let transparentGainImage = colorMatrixFilter.outputImage!
```

Comment: Learned something new today. Thanks Frank!